# How do you select a number of random rows from different AgeGroup?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a for loop in python to connect it to Snowflake since Snowflake does not support loops. 
I want to select a number of random rows from different AgeGroups. eg. 1500 rows from AgeGroup "30-40", 1200 rows from AgeGroup "40-50" , 875 rows from AgeGroup "50-60".

Any ideas how to do it or an alternative method for a loop in Snowflake?

Comment: Could you share some of your data, desired result, and what you have tried?

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at Snowflake's Stored Procedures?  They are Javascript and would allow you to loop natively in Snowflake:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-overview.html

Comment: Stored procedures are important and you can certainly loop with them, but in this case there exists a reasonably non-complex solution in plain SQL, which can also be tricked to do loopy stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to draw `n` random samples from each group you could create a subquery containing a row number that is randomly distributed within each group, and then select the top `n` rows from each group.

If you have a table like this:

```
USER    DATE
1       2018-11-04
1       2018-11-04
1       2018-12-07
1       2018-10-09
1       2018-10-09
1       2018-11-07
1       2018-11-09
1       2018-11-09
2       2019-11-02
2       2019-10-02
2       2019-11-03
2       2019-11-06
3       2019-11-10
3       2019-11-13
3       2019-11-15
```

This query could be used to return two random rows for User 2 and 3, and 3 random rows for user 1:

```
SELECT User, Date 
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY User ORDER BY RANDOM()) as random_row 
    FROM Users) 
WHERE 
    (User = 3 AND random_row < 3) OR 
    (User = 2 AND random_row < 3) OR 
    (User = 1 AND random_row < 4);
```

So in your case partition on and filter `age_group` instead of `User`.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "Snowflake doesn't have loops"?  SQL has "loops" if you can find them...

The following query does what you asked for:

```
WITH POPULATION AS ( /* 10,000 persons with random age 0-100 */
  SELECT 'Person ' || SEQ2() ID, ABS(RANDOM()) % 100 AGE
  FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 10000))
)
SELECT
  ID,
  AGE,
  CASE
    WHEN AGE < 30 THEN '0-30'
    WHEN AGE < 40 THEN '30-40'
    WHEN AGE < 50 THEN '40-50'
    WHEN AGE < 60 THEN '50-60'
    ELSE '60-100'
  END AGE_GROUP,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AGE_GROUP ORDER BY RANDOM()) DRAW_ORDER
FROM POPULATION
QUALIFY DRAW_ORDER <= DECODE(AGE_GROUP, '30-40', 1500, '40-50', 1200, '50-60', 875, 0);
```

**Addendum**:

As pointed out by [waldente](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744096/waldente), a simpler and more efficient way is to use `SAMPLE`:

```
WITH
POPULATION_30_40 AS (SELECT * FROM POPULATION WHERE AGE >= 30 AND AGE < 40),
POPULATION_40_50 AS (SELECT * FROM POPULATION WHERE AGE >= 40 AND AGE < 50),
POPULATION_50_60 AS (SELECT * FROM POPULATION WHERE AGE >= 50 AND AGE < 60)
SELECT * FROM POPULATION_30_40 SAMPLE(1500 ROWS) UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM POPULATION_40_50 SAMPLE(1200 ROWS) UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM POPULATION_50_60 SAMPLE(875 ROWS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake has support for random and deterministic table sampling. For Example:

Return a sample of a table in which each row has a 10% probability of being included in the sample:

```
SELECT * FROM testtable SAMPLE (10);
```

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constructs/sample.html

Comment: Surely you can do non-trivial sampling directly with Snowflake, but not at the detail level asked for here...

Comment: Have you considered: `select * from t sample (1200 rows) where AgeGroup between 30 and 40 union all <... next clause>`.  The idea is that sample is potentially more efficient than order by random().  And offers repeatability.

Comment: You are totally correct.  Using `SAMPLE` and `UNION` is clearly the simplest solution and probably the most efficient as well.